# Changing database asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database-design

I am building a project on asp.net with sql database.

I want to update a row in the table.

the table name - parkingLots , the column I want to update is - "free spaces".

this is the code I wrote but it does'nt do the updating in the table:

```
var arduinoQuery1 = from b in db.parkingLots
                    where b.parkingLotID == 1
                    select b;

foreach (parkingLot b in arduinoQuery1)
{
    b.freeSpaces = space;
}
```

I want to make free spaces of this specific row to be equal to "space".
How do I do that?

Comment: You set b.freeSpaces, but you never save that to the database.

Comment: Are you calling ```db.SaveChanges();``` somewhere?

Comment: Where are you actually updating the database? I don't see where you're saving the transaction.

Comment: Indeed, it won't.. all you've done there is download some data into a list, then run through the list in your program memory, changing some values

Comment: call `db.SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write

db.savechange()

in foreach loop

Comment: And why do you suggest to do that within the loop and not outside it?

Comment: because in that way entity write back the changes to the db for every single entity i always write like that and i never get error

Comment: You should state your reasoning as part of your answer, rather than just assuming everyone will know why you do it that way.